# How to reload changed lua module/script?

Tags: c++, lua

I want dynamically reload *.lua file on "C/C++" side when it changes.
How to do it in proper way? I found answers which describes process on the "Lua" side. Set ***package.loaded.??? = nil*** and ***require*** automatically reload it, but i not have that part.

I try next code (only for test purposes):

```
void loadScript(lua_State* l, const std::string& f_path) {
    int error = luaL_loadfile(l, f_path.c_str()) || lua_pcall(l, 0, 0, 0);
    cout << "load file result: " << error << endl;
}
```

Which I am calls every time when content *f_path* was changed.

It works fine, but i have assumption:

1. Every time when i load same file - i not reload it, i just add new item to "*lua stack*" and execute whats on top of stack (latest item which was loaded).
2. File which will be reloaded probably should not have global variables.
3. I have filling: "defiantly doing something wrong".

I need clarification how it should be and get understanding how it works.

Comment: I know when it was changed it`s not problem.

Comment: From the Lua reference manual "Loads a Lua chunk without running it. If there are no errors, lua_load pushes the compiled chunk as a Lua function on top of the stack."  So assumption 1 is correct.

Comment: @Piglet If (1) assumption correct then (3) correct too. And this code probably blow up application memory usage every time when i try reload Lua script (make complete mess). I actually wonder that i can not find answer/example/instruction on my question: "How to reload script in proper way?". Or I am missing something.

Comment: If someone  familiar with python i looking an analogue of PyImport_ReloadModule  in Lua C-API.

Comment: why not simply clear the stack befor loading the new chunk?

Comment: @Piglet Actually I can do that. Holding *lua_State* per module and drop it when module was changed and than load it from clear point - not hard for my project. Because every Lua module not has external dependency and this my pet-project. But i want to know is exists variant to hold everything in one state and reload  changed part - just for educational purposes..

Comment: @DeadWarlock There's no way doing so without sandboxing `pcall`ed function, because that function has access to complete `lua_State` and can change everything that can influence first reloading of the script. The simplest way of such sandboxing would be creating `lua_newstate` and closing previously created one.